# Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations when using my own library

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-workspace-configuration

I created a workspace with applications and my first library which was created with the command `ng g library breeze-helpers` (breeze-helpers is the name of my library)

Then I built the library with `ng build breeze-helpers --watch`. It is successfully compiled to the `dist` folder of my workspace.

In the main tsconfig file the following was added automatically:

```
"paths": {     
      "breeze-helpers": [
        "dist/breeze-helpers/breeze-helpers",
        "dist/breeze-helpers"
      ]
    }
```

I then imported the library in one of my applications :

```
import { BreezeHelpersModule } from 'breeze-helpers';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
 
  ],
  imports: [
    BreezeHelpersModule
  ],
```

and I can use it in my code :

```
import { EntityManagerService } from 'breeze-helpers';
```

Visual Studio Code provides me with intellisense and no errors is found. However when I build my application with `ng build my-app`  I get plenty of errors :

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm missing. I've been following this [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I had to create a simlink as explained [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1193/create-your-standalone-angular-library-in-10-minutes)

```
$ cd ./dist/my-lib
$ npm link

$ cd my-app
$ npm link my-lib
```